# "I prefer riding to walking" VERSUS "I prefer to ride than to walk"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

**Original question:** I prefer riding than/to walking

I came across this exercise question in a book.

The correct statement according to the book is:

> I prefer riding to walking

Why is it **to** instead of **than**?

Answered by [Jack O'Flaherty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/254868/116056)

---

The new version of this question is suggested by Lambie

> I prefer riding to walking
> **VERSUS**
> I prefer to ride than to walk

Are both correct? If so, when do we use which?

Comment: @Lambie I have modified the question.

Comment: Now you need to read my answer. The answer you chose is not correct. The answer misquotes the Cambridge Dictionary: She prefers books to magazines. Not: She prefers books than magazines.

Comment: @Lambie Jack's answer to the original question is very much correct.

Comment: No, it is not. It is wrong and he misuses the Cambridge Dictionary thing about the use of than **which states you cannot use than like this**: I prefer x THAN y.

Comment: Thank you for that!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "to" is required by the verb "prefer". You prefer one thing **to** another.

[Cambridge Dictionary "expressing preference"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/prefer)
"We use prefer to say we like one thing or activity more than another.
We can use a prepositional phrase with **to** when we compare two things or actions"

That dictionary points out that we don't use "than" with "prefer".

The word "than" could be used in a statement like this:
"There is more riding than walking."

Comment: I prefer riding to walking VERSUS I prefer to ride than to walk.

Comment: You are misquoting the dictionary: She prefers x than y.

Comment: @Lambie The dictionary, at the link I gave, says, plain as day, "We don’t use than after prefer". Have you looked at it?

Comment: Lambie, I think @Jack hasn't misquoted anything. It looks correct. Infact I accepted that as an answer after going through the link and my books.

Comment: @Jack Kindly look into the second part of the question conveniently. And I didn't mean any offence by reverting the accepted answer.

Comment: @Severus As far as I understand, "I prefer to ride than to walk." is not grammatical. If you insisted on using to-infinitives there, you'd have to say "I prefer to ride to to walk.", but no one would say that. If you use bare infinitives, you could say "I prefer 'ride' to 'walk'.", but only referring to the words, not the actions. A valid sentence using to-infinitves would be "I `like` to ride more than to walk." Also, "prefer" occurs with "over", as in "I prefer riding over walking."

Comment: The Cambridge Dictionary says this:
"She prefers books to magazines. **Not**: She **prefers books than magazines**." It does **not say** you don't say: I prefer to swim than to play. Therefore, your answer misquotes it and leaves out the alternative way to saying it. The CD says nothing about that at all and my answer is perfectly grammatical.

Comment: **I prefer to ride than to walk** is 100% grammatical. prefer has the to followed by a verb and a comparative.

Comment: @Lambie `She prefers books to magazines. Not: She prefers books than magazines` That's what Jack has been saying. I have not been able to figure out what is the mistake that you are trying to point out.

Comment: @SeverusSnape He says the dictionary says "we don't use *than* with prefer", which is not accurate. We don't use *than* like this: *I prefer books than movies*. Only that is wrong. Not what I wrote, which is **different**. I prefer reading books rather than watching movies! I prefer to read books (rather) than watch movies. If you cannot see the difference, that's the problem. It's different.

Comment: **I prefer riding (rather) than walking**. also one 100% grammatical.

Answer (score -4):

- **I prefer walking to riding**
- **I prefer walking (rather) than riding**.
- **I prefer to walk (rather) than to ride**.
- **I prefer books *than* TV**. [BUZZER, NOT GRAMMATICAL]

Both those are acceptable. What the Cambridge Dictionary **does not accept** is:
I prefer x than y.

Conclusion: It is not *to* instead of **than**. The difference is the first is a noun (walking) whereas the second one is a verb phrase after to.

Please note: than means rather than.

**On an official IELTS site:**

> would prefer + infinitive + rather than + base form of verb
> = to want to do one thing more than another thing. (in the present or future) (“rather than” separates the 2 activities that we are
> comparing. The activity before “rather than” is the one we want to do
> the most.)
>
> Examples:
>
> **I would prefer to go to New York rather than go to Los Angeles.**
> Jane:
> **I’d prefer to walk rather than get a taxi.**

Please note: Those examples are for would prefer but they work for prefer alone.

[Crown Academy of English](https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/verb-prefer-english/)

Here is what the founder of that site says about himself.

**My name is Andrew and I am the founder of Crown Academy of English. I am British and a native English speaker. I was born in the city of Manchester in England.
I am a fully qualified English teacher. In 2003, I passed the Trinity CertTESOL qualification ( Certificate in Teaching English to Speakers of Other Languages), one of the most respected English teaching qualifications and recognised internationally by the British Council.**

Please note: In speech, we often *drop the rather* with *than* so that **rather than** just becomes *than.*

Comment: Downvoters, you do not know your English. Sorry.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard anyone say something like "I prefer walking than riding". That must be a regional thing; I'm pretty sure people here in Grand Rapids don't say that.

Comment: @TannerSwett It is short for *rather than*. I prefer walking rather than riding. People often drop the rather in speech: I prefer walking than riding. And Grand Rapids means nothing in this regard per se.

Comment: All about biking: So that blows that myth out of the water. **Women prefer riding than playing with kids**, being with a newborn baby, probably even more than having sex....maybe. http://www.cosportbikeclub.org/forums/showthread.php?37729-Male-Bikers-Prefer-Women-Over-Motorcycles

Comment: I repeat: someone is looking through my answers and downvoting them. I hope he or she is having fun.

Comment: @TannerSwett If you only take Grand Rapids into account, there is probably a ton of other stuff that we might disagree on. I do encourage: **rather than** but the rather is sometimes left out by speakers.